# Pass a variable parameter to pgr_dijkstra (pgRouting) Edges SQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, pgrouting, plpgsql

I need to pass a parameter to Edges SQL in a pgRouting function, for example pgr_dijkstra.

I try something like:

```
PREPARE test (int) AS
INSERT INTO   elab.test_f 
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM elab.temp_grafo_archi WHERE g_id = $1',
2, 3
);

EXECUTE test(1)
```

But I get
ERROR:  there is no parameter $1.

It works if I use start_vid or end_vid as parameter. But i need to parametrize Edges SQL

```
PREPARE test (int) AS
INSERT INTO   elab.test_f 
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM elab.temp_grafo_archi WHERE g_id = 1',
$, 3
);

EXECUTE test(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string literal has no reference to anywhere outside of it - you will need to create the `Edge SQL` string from any of PostgreSQL's [*String Functions and Operators*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html).

Using the most versatile `FORMAT`:

```
PREPARE test (int) AS
  INSERT INTO elab.test_f 
    SELECT *
    FROM
      pgr_dijkstra(
        FORMAT(
          $FORMAT$
          SELECT
            id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost
          FROM
            elab.temp_grafo_archi
          WHERE
            g_id = %1$s
          $FORMAT$,
          $1     -- PREPARE param get's injected into FORMAT
        ),
        2, 3
      )
;
```